# Compile error with aarch64-linux-musl-cross but not with gcc/g++ (error: ‘string’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type)

Tags: cross-compiling, musl, vsomeip

I'm trying to cross compile vSOMEIP and CommonAPI for ARM with [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org) (aarch64-linux-musl-cross). I use the following versions:

- [CommonAPI 3.1.10.1](https://github.com/COVESA/capicxx-core-runtime/archive/refs/tags/3.1.10.1.zip) - successfully compiled
- [Boost 1.59.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.59.0/boost_1_59_0.zip)
- [vsomeip 2.14.16](https://github.com/COVESA/vsomeip/archive/refs/tags/2.14.16.zip) - compile error

Further, I'm using a Docker container to compile everything.
With *"docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 .."* and gcc/g++ every works fine, no compile errors.

However, when I'm using *"docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 .."* and gcc/g++ or musl-lib, I get the following compile error:

```
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/vsomeip.dir/implementation/endpoints/src/credentials.cpp.o
In file included from /home/Workspace/lib/vsomeip/implementation/endpoints/src/../include/credentials.hpp:9,
                 from /home/Workspace/lib/vsomeip/implementation/endpoints/src/credentials.cpp:10:
/home/Workspace/lib/vsomeip/interface/vsomeip/primitive_types.hpp:42:14: error: ‘string’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
   42 | typedef std::string trace_channel_t;
      |              ^~~~~~
/home/Workspace/lib/vsomeip/interface/vsomeip/primitive_types.hpp:11:1: note: ‘std::string’ is defined in header ‘<string>’; did you forget to ‘#include <string>’?
   10 | #include <cstdint>
  +++ |+#include <string>
   11 |
```

I haven't any idea why the string include or the std namespace creates an error? Can someone help me please. Thanks a lot.

I would like to use the commonAPI/vsomeip [COVESA](https://github.com/COVESA) middleware and communication configuration for my system. After long trying the mentioned version above are the ones which are working together.

--
For the full picture, in addition to the mentioned versions above the following components are also needed to implement a full working system of provider and consumer:

- [SOMEIP runtime 3.1.10.4](https://github.com/COVESA/capicxx-someip-runtime/archive/refs/tags/3.1.10.4.zip)
- CommonAPI generator 3.1.10
- SOMEIP generator 3.1.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in

/home/Workspace/lib/vsomeip/interface/vsomeip/primitive_types.hpp

`#include <string>`

Comment: Yes, thanks that works. However, I'm questioning, why this error doesn't occur with g++.